# Map edditor 'Tiled' will not export?

Tags: maps, export, fedora, tile

I am working with [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) on Fedora 19 64 bit. I installed Tiled via `sudo yum install tiled` which installed Tiled version 0.9.1-1.

I have experience with Tiled on windows, so I created a simple map to test if the install was working, but when I went to export the map (File > Export as...), it came up with the error:

[image]

I have tried forcing a file extension onto the end of the exported name (such as .txt), but nothing works. Do I need to install/create a file exporter for Tiled in Linux? Or is there some config file I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Seems like an issue with the Fedora 19 build. I built tiled from source and it resolved the issue:

```
sudo yum remove tiled
sudo yum install qt-devel
git clone https://github.com/bjorn/tiled.git
cd tiled
qmake-qt4
make
sudo make install
```